# Python Budget Code Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue with the following code. When the user selects N I keep getting an error message:

```
budget = input("please enter the budget amount for given month\n ")
sum_ = 0
expense = 0
i = 0

print("Please enter the expenses for the given month:")
while (1):
   expense1 = input("Please enter expense number " + str(i + 1) + " \n")
   sum_ = sum_ + int(expense)
   c = input("If you want to enter more expense press y else n \n")
   if c == 'y':
      i += 1
      continue
   else:
      break
if sum_ > budget:
   print("You went over budget")
else:
   print("You are under budget")
```

Comment: So, what's the error message? Also, please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Bug 1.  When I run this with Python 3, I get

```
If you want to enter more expense press y else n 
n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\python34\tem.py", line 16, in <module>
    if sum_ > budget:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

You should have looked at the error message.  It says that `sum_` is an int and `budget` is a string.  The obvious fix is to make `budget` an int with `int(budget)`.  If you really could not figure this out, you should probably look at the tutorial more.  In any case, you should have posted it as Kevin suggested.

Bug 2.  You initialized expense to 0.  This masked the bug of calling the entered expense `expense1`.  So you only add `int(0)` to the initially 0 `sum_`.  The fix is to drop the initialization and correct the misspelling.  You should also print the sum at the end to so you can check that it is correct.

Buglet 3. Having to say y/n to enter another expense is really annoying.  Just stop when the user does not enter anything.

Answer (score -2):

Two pieces of your code to give you a hint:

```
budget = input("please enter the budget amount for given month\n ")

expense1 = input("Please enter expense number " + str(i + 1) + " \n")
sum_ = sum_ + int(expense)
```

Notice some difference?

Also, do not use str(i + 1). `"Please blah blah {0} blah\n".format(i + 1)`.